# Jquery function not running together

Tags: jquery

First function is

```
    $(function() {
        var pull        = $('#pull');
            menu        = $('.mnav ul');
            menuHeight  = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
    });
```

and second function is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#id1").click(function(){$("#id1").hide();$("#std_show").slideDown("slow");});
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var text = escape($.trim($('textarea#form_text').val()));
        var code = escape($.trim($('input#form_code').val()));
        $('div#form_text_info').html('');
        $('div#form_code_info').html('');
        $('div#std_form_info').html('');
        var save = true;
        /*somthing*/
    });
});
```

Both function not running together ? If name problem the give solution, because I'm beginner in JQ

Comment: Both function correct . I'm asking how any of one rename function?

Comment: is there an error here that you're getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Both `$(function() {` and `$(document).ready(function() {` are the same. The first is merely a shorthand form of the second.

Both the function do nothing on their own except they hook click events on some html elements.

These are fired when the document is ready (the browser has created the DOM)

Answer (score 0):

One of the important standards to be followed while scripting using jQuery is to Use only one DOCUMENT 'Ready' function for a page.

You can either use $(document).ready(function(){}) OR $(function(){}).

The latter is the shorthand format of the former as mentioned by @UmairP. There is no problem with your code. Just merge the ready functions into one and try again.

Happy Scripting !!!